# RFID wristband for cashless payments

Tags: rfid, nfc

Most cashless payment systems using RFID seem to use HF (13.5MHz) tags. My questions are:

1. **Why do RFID wristbands used for cashless payments use HF over LF transponders?** Some access control applications seem to use LF transponders (tags) and I would have thought that the use-case for cashless payments (proximity of access card/wristband to a reader) is similar.
2. There are a multitude of standards for contactless ICs:

   - ISO14443 for proximity contanctless cards [even within this, I
     believe there are variations.]
   - ISO15693 for vicinity contactless
     cards
   - ISO18000 set of standards for RFIDs EPCglobal Class 1 Gen 2
     (=18000-6C)

   **Would I be right in understanding that for cashless payments using RFID wristbands, I should be looking at ISO14443 compliant tags** (i.e., HF tags that have a range of ~10cm)?
3. Some existing cashless payment systems (for example, the one described in [this](https://www.intellitix.com/resources/newsarticle/144) example) seem to require a "double-tap" - once for reading wristband data and the second, for writing back (balance amount). **Is a double-tap unavoidable?**

**EDIT:** Some over-zealous moderation has resulted in this question being put on hold. I had done my research and had asked very specific questions, each of which could have been answered by someone knowledgeable in the field, with a sentence or two, so I don't understand the rationale for moderation. Luckily for me, a kind soul answered my questions just in time. Thank you Nils!

Comment: #4 removed, because it's off-topic for EE.SE .  #1 through #3 may have to be posted as separate questions (perhaps with links to each other).  An overall snag with this post is that it deals with a mix of RF and financial transaction requirements (such as security).

Comment: I'll leave the debate over relevance to others. But I believe the choice of RF in wristbands is because RF performs better around high water content objects.  eg fruit and bodies :)

Comment: Sorry. That should have been HF not RF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do RFID wristbands used for cashless payments use HF over LF
>   transponders?

There was an easy migration path from contact based chip-cards to HF contactless. On the application level some of the HF tags support the same ISO7816-4 protocol that the chip based credit-cards understand.

For LF tags no such simple update was possible. That's why HF was the natural choice.

> Would I be right in understanding that for cashless payments using
>   RFID wristbands, I should be looking at ISO14443 compliant tags.

Yes, if you want to interact with existing point-of-sales terminals you're pretty forced to use ISO14443-A and ISO14443-B tags. If you roll your own payment terminals you have more choices.

> Is a double-tap unavoidable?

No, it is an implementation detail of this technology. You don't need to double-tap if you use contactless credit cards for example.